# How can I isolate one column based on another?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that is set up like this:

```
Name | Account | Contracts
Alpha| AE123   | 456
Alpha| RC345   | 3
Alpha| PO870   | 67
Bravo| ER908   | 1090
Bravo| MN556   | 76
Bravo| EU231   | 879
```

I want the account associated with each Name with the highest Contracts. I've tried a few versions of Greatest() but couldn't quite isolate it to what I want. I want the end result to look like:

```
Name | Account | Contracts
Alpha| AE123   | 456
Bravo| ER908   | 1090
```

I thought about using Distinct but there are multiple Alpha names. So a lot of the "select Distinct(Name) where xxx" are out.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table
where true 
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by Name order by Contracts desc)
```

if apply to sample data in your question -output is

[image]